# Can you switch the order in the chain rule?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

$$\frac{\partial \mu(v)}{\partial v}\bigg\vert_{v(\dot{q})} \frac{\partial v}{\partial \dot{q}} \stackrel{{\color{red}?}}{=} \frac{\partial v}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{\partial \mu(v)}{\partial v}\bigg\vert_{v(\dot{q})}$$

Why is this a valid transformation? I thought the chain rule worked in one direction so to speak:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg\vert_{x(t)}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Comment: Multiplication is commutative

Comment: I thought the chain rule was not commutative. How can I differentiate $v$ with respect to $\dot{q}$ and then differentiate with respect to $v$ and have that equal to the opposite case?

Comment: Ignore the chain rule, let's just focus on what you've written. $$\mu(v)\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial q}\cdot\mu(v)$$All that's happened there is you have taken a multiplication $a\cdot b$ and replaced it with $b\cdot a$ which is fine in the real numbers

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t that bit. Please help explain why that first operation is valid? I am really confused and would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: This is *not* changing the order of differentiation. This *is* changing the order of multiplication. I haven't actually done anything

Comment: Are we sure this is multiplication of just real numbers? Often the chain rule is dealing with functions of vector variables. Is $v$ a scalar function or a vector function? With multivariable functions, it is helpful to think about composing linear mappings to understand the chain rule.